# Darcy's law for a funnel shape

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I'm currently investigating how water moves through coffee in a classic pour-over coffee. [image]

I want to apply Darcy's law on a funnel shape but I'm not sure how to do it because the cross-section area changes throughout the funnel. My idea is to use the differential form of Darcy's law, and then integrate it over the shape. Differential form:

[image]

Here q is the instantaneous flow defined by Q/A. My idea was to rewrite $$\frac{\Delta p}{L}=\frac{dp}{dy}$$
Assuming that the pressure only works in the vertical direction because the symmetry of the funnel would leave only the y-component of the change in pressure. Then we could write:
$$\frac{Q}{A}=-\frac{kdp}{\mu dy}$$
My problem is now how do I define the cross-section area A so I can integrate over it?

Comment: Even though it is axially symmetric, the pressure does vary radially.

Comment: Are you interested in the pressure distribution or the velocity distribution?

Comment: Doesn't the coffee flow under gravity?  Where is the gravitational term in your equations?

Comment: I was just interested in integrating to get an expression for the flowrate Q. I don't think the pressure is radial because the movement of the fluid would still be vertical. And yeah the gravity term is hidden in the pressure difference term because the weight of the water exerts pressure on the water below. But I think I worked out the problem. I just have to write the radius as an expression depending on y by using trigonometry, then the integration can be done.

Comment: Do you think it would be vertical, right through the side of the funnel?